# How to set the current shell settings to every shell i a bash?

Tags: bash, shell

I have done some 'source file' at the current bash shell and want that file to be sourced to every shell that is created. How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an entry in your .bashrc file. If one doesn't exist, go to your home directory and create one with your favorite text editor.

For more info on the .bashrc file and what it can do, check out [this site](http://ss64.com/bash/syntax.html). Also, read the man bash page for an exhaustive amount of detail.

Comment: Thank you. It worked. Till now I have been trying to change some bashrc and bash_profile in some other directory. Now I have created a new .bashrc in my Home directory and it worked.